# Unpickle Celery results in BLOB using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, celery, blob, pickle

I am using the Oracle `result_backend` to store the Celery results, which are in BLOB format. When I connect to the db with python and use `pickle.loads()` it will work, but when I try to decode them in Oracle SQL using `to_char(dbms_lob.substr(BLOB_FIELD))` did not work.

e.g. instead of `echo 'Test'` I see `��`

Comment: What character-encoding is being used?

Comment: Also, exactly what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Why are you using `lob.substr` at all here?

Comment: ASCII and Oracle Database 19c.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use pickle? You can chose serialisation protocol for results, and make it JSON for an example.

Comment: I don't use `pickle`. It's built into `celery`.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend you to change result serialisation to use JSON or YAML. It should be as simple as setting the [result_serializer](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#result-serializer) parameter to 'json' or 'yaml'. I know very little about Oracle, but I would assume it knows nothing about Python's pickle...

Celery older than 4.0 used pickle by default. They changed that to JSON in 4.0 and later versions.

Comment: I am already using the default serializer which is `json`.